# How does this show the system is linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

This
[image]

I know for a system to be linear, it has to obey superposition, but how did they go from the combined equation to the 2 equations x(t) = ... and y(t) = ...

Did they solve the ODE and just omit the steps?

edit: does this belong in an electrical engineering stack exchange?

Answer (score 1):

They did not solve the ODE. They are saying that, given two pairs of solutions $(x_1(t),y_1(t))$ and $(x_2(t),y_2(t))$, the linear combination $(k_1x_1(t) + k_2x_2(t), k_1y_1(t) + k_2y_2(t))$ is also a solution to the given ODE. Consequently, the given ODE is linear.

Comment: I'd mention $x$ is clearly linear in $y$, and also as you show $y$ can be made linear in $x$.

Comment: I get that given 2 pairs of solutions, their linear combination SHOULD be a solution, but how did they show anything? There is no "proof" or convincing demonstration, they pretty much just stated the linear combination is a solution to the ODE. Whatever happened to the d/dt part of the equation?

Comment: @reuns, i don't understand can you elaborate?

Comment: @Prof As a function of $x$, $y$ is well-defined only up to the solutions for $x= 0$, but then you'll find a *linear operator* giving the solutions $y = Tx = x \ast h$ where $\ast$ is the convolution

Comment: @reruns, appologies, i didn't find that any more revealing. how is convolution useful here? What does "only up to the solutions for x=0" "up-to" - from where? Pretend you're speaking to a 10 year old with me

Comment: @Prof They proved that on the second and third bullet point.